# Difference between EasyUEFI boot item and mounted disk folder

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi, diskpart

Few days ago I tried to remove PhoenixOS boot entry (=android like system) via efibootmgr command and EasyUEFI. Now it looks like, that sometimes it is not visible in Linux, sometimes it is. However, in EasyUEFI it is always visible.
[image]

Though, when I mount the EFI volume (260 MB) there is no file looking like bootx64.efi, nor even folder like that. 
[image]

Previously, I moved whole \Boot folder with bootx64.efi in ubuntu away. I am not aware that there was folder "PhoenixOS". Why is there such difference between EasyUEFI and Windows file system?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit complicated, it deals with some pitfalls I did.

**A. Copy back the Boot to your ESP**

\Boot\bootx64.efi to ESP (=Efi system partition) \EFI\

(I did this step in ubuntu, and do not describe it in detail here)
... if you have not deleted it yet. It is (probably) NOT the same file as:
\EFI\PhoenixOS\Boot\bootx64.efi

found by EasyUEFI.

**B. If your plan is to unistall Phoenix OS, find proper instructions**

For me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcRS7dHdK20 looks reasonable.
Even better looks its commentary:

1. Uninstall Phoenix os in programs and features (control panel > program)
2. Press w+ s then type disk > choose creat or format disk.... Then format the partition ( use format type as your main local disk format.) If fat2 then fat2 or etc. After that delete volume/patrition.
3. Control panel > system > advanced setting > Advanced> startup & boot > setting > choose phoenix os and untick it if it still there.

Lastly press powers till the computer off then on again. Goodluck.

*If you format first without uninstall, there a chance that the phoenix os still appears in boot menu.﻿

**C. When you cannot unnistal Phoenix OS.**

(you damaged files, you already deleted its partition, whatever is the reason)
... and everything else is working (dual booting in my case with ubuntu) and at the same time you are not very experienced as I am you should consider let it as it is.
But when you are bit obsessed with uninstallation of Phoenix OS this helped me to do so (it is not difficult):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY

I just needed these steps, everything else I did unknowingly before:

2.1.2 to view all boot related entry. Type to administrator command promt in Windows 10:

```
bcdedit /enum all
```

2.1.3 Copy and paste the UUID of the entry (UUID = first item called identifier).
(I hope it was \EFI\PhoenixOS\Boot\bootx64.efi). Definitely do not go to next step if you are not sure you chose the correct item.
Select - Right Click.

2.1.4 Type

```
bcdedit /delete {code of UUID}
```

And that is it. After this you should not see entry of Phoenix OS in EasyUEFI (and also not in ubuntu if you have one).